# PDOException in PHP in a server not local

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, nginx

I am working on nginx server which is not in my local machine. I have mysql workbench where i store database. I have a database in my mysql workbench. In laravel when i run the command **php artisan migrate** to connect with the database, i get the following error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = database_name and table_name = migrations)
  [PDOException]
  could not find driver
```

My .env file is like the following:

```
APP_ENV=local 

APP_KEY=applicaion_key

APP_DEBUG=true

APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug

APP_URL=host address of mysql server

DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=ip address of the host of mysql workbench

DB_PORT=3306 // 

DB_DATABASE=database_name

DB_USERNAME=username

DB_PASSWORD=mysql workbench password
```

Comment: I think this is quey level exception, You need to have a module called `pdo_mysql`. Make sure on your server PDO MYSQL installed.

Comment: Seems like you don't have php-mysql installed on your server.

Comment: Even if php-pdo is installed, you still need php-mysql to be able to use it for mysql as @gpasci suggests. PDO is only an abstraction layer and doesn't contain the actually drivers...

Comment: Using $ php -m command,  i found the following modules:

calendar

Core

ctype

date

exif

fileinfo

filter

ftp

gettext

hash

iconv

json

libxml

openssl

pcntl

pcre

PDO

Phar

posix

readline

Reflection

session

shmop

sockets

SPL

standard

sysvmsg

sysvsem

sysvshm

tokenizer

Zend OPcache

zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache

Comment: There you go! You're missing the mysql extension and need to install it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one thing, is the name of the module 'pdo_mysql' or 'php-mysql'?

Comment: The name is: `php-mysql`

Comment: Thank you all guys. It worked finally :)